# Is an indefinite Snackbar a viable option for progress indication?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, user-experience

As Android developers, we should avoid using `ProgressDialog` as it is now deprecated.

From general UI/UX perspective: is it a good idea to use an indefinite `Snackbar` for progress indication?
Also, what do material guidelines say about it?

Would love to hear your opinion on this, as well as some use case examples where it should or should not be used.

Thanks!

Comment: I went from using a progress dialog to using a progress bar instead. Not sure what you mean when you say using a snack bar  to indicate progress. This question in generall though is inviting opinion answers and that's considered off-topic here.

Comment: Well, for example: putting ```ProgressBar``` inside ```Snackbar``` instead of other UI elements. Also (*getting off-topic here*): aren't all answers just someone's opinion?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with every SO policy but I do respect them. Also, most well-written answers here aren't opinions; they're explanations of how programming languages work. My comment above was just my opinion but someone else might say that they wouldn't recommend it. I'm just telling you that this could easily turn into a forum-thread-like conversation based on opinions that some SO moderator will eventually close after marking it off-topic.